# Custom button image in tableview cell isnt changing?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Ive got a custom tableview with a label and button. When the button is pressed on an individual cell, the image should change. But it doesnt?

so it logs "testing" when I click the individual custom tableview cell button, but the image doesnt change.

```
@IBAction func tickAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println("testing")

    if let image = UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forState: .Normal)

    }
    if let image = UIImage(named:"Checked") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. Which image you are checking?

try to do it like:

```
@IBAction func tickAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println("testing")

    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = false
    }
    else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: error given: 'UIButton' does not have a member names isSelected

Comment: There is two images. When button is pressed it switches from Unchecked to Checked and viceversa

Comment: So i press the button and the image changed. But if i press the button again, the image doesnt change back to unchecked

Comment: @MiryJone Try correcting image name from "Checked" to "Checked.png"

Comment: @MiryJone Welcome anytime :)

Comment: Is there a way to take the cell that is checked and append it to an array  .. like an array that only lists 'checked' data?

Comment: @MiryJone you can do it like create array in view did load with number of rows with default value 0, update that row to 1 when you click on cell. There are many ways to do it. based on the opinions.

Comment: how to get the cell data thoguh of only the selected.   is it cell.selected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31335133/swift-how-to-add-to-an-array-when-button-is-pressed