# How to add to an array when button is pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I've got custom buttons on a custom tableview cell, when button is pressed the image changes to checked/unchecked (see code below).

Issues is: How do I add the cell row data thats checked to an array that will be its own table (eg. a table with only checked data).

```
@IBAction func tickAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println("SSSS")

    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Unchecked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = false
    }
    else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named:"Checked.png"), forState: .Normal)
        sender.selected = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to extend UITableViewCell into your own class that holds the other data or holds a reference to a model that holds the data.

Ideally, the view controller should hold the models and should get notified by a view that the action took place to act accordingly. The view controller should then add the data to the other array.

Comment: from the code above, How do i get the row of the button clicked?